# Is there a way to get all classes from Parse in PHP SDK?

Tags: php, parse-platform

I have an account on [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) and i created some **classes**, such as products, users, roles, brands, ...etc

Is there a way to get a **list of those classes using PHP-SDK**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ParseSchema` class to access the list of classes you have created.

```
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseSchema;

$app_id = '';
$master_key = '';
$rest_key  = '';

$parse = ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );

$schemas = new ParseSchema();

$classes = $schemas->all();

var_dump($classes);
```